# How to create scoped Guice providers for data objects?

Tags: java, guice

My question is, how do I use the power of guice providers (their ability to scope instances), for data objects?

Here is the rationale: I have a session-scoped class `WebPage` that fetches data upon a web request from a database object `DAO`.

```
//Scope of WebPage: SESSION
class WebPage{
  Provider<DAO> daoProvider; //Scope of DAO: REQUEST

  WebPage(Provider<DAO> daoProvider){
     this.daoProvider = daoProvider;
  }

  public String getMyString(){
    return daoProvider.get().getMyString();
  }

  public int getMyInt(){
    return daoProvider.get().getMyInt();
  }
}
```

The `WebPage` object is part of a web framework which keeps all page objects in session. Upon each request `getMyString` and `getMyInt` methods are called several times to fetch values before displaying them to the user on the page. Assume that `DAO` object is attached to one particular row in a table and just fetches data from that row.

For performance reasons, I need `daoProvider` to always return the same instance, to avoid reconnection to the database every time `getMyString` or `getMyInt` is called. On the other hand, the instance has to be renewed across requests, to make any updates to the database visible to users after page refresh.

So what I am looking for is a request-scoped provider of `DAO` inside a session-scoped `WebPage` object. The problem is I don't understand how to wire it up in Guice. I have tried this but to no avail:

```
class DAO{
  Result row;

  DAO(int rowId){
    //opens DB connection and establishes a link
    //to the object in question
    this.row = attachRow(rowId);
  }

  String getMyString(){
    this.row.getData("mystring");
  }

  int getMyInt(){
    this.row.getIntData("myint");
  }
}

interface DAOProviderFactory {
  Provider<DAO> create(int rowId);
}

class DAOProviderFactoryImpl implements DAOProviderFactory {
  @Override
  public Provider<DAO> create(int rowId) {
    return new DAOProviderImpl(rowId);
  }
}

@RequestScoped
class DAOProviderImpl implements Provider<DAO> {
  int rowId;

  public DAOProviderImpl(int rowId) {
    this.rowId = rowId;
  }

  @Override
  public DAO get() {
    //I want this instance to be request-scoped!
    return new DAO(rowId);
  }
}

//Then bind it in the module
bind(DAOProviderFactory.class).to(DAOProviderFactoryImpl.class);
```

This did not work, as calling `daoProvider.get()` would return a new instance (unscoped) every call. I guess the reason for this is that my `DAOProviderImpl` object is not acually managed by Guice. Another problem is the fair amount of boiler-plate.

How can I serve an instance of `DAO` with a particular `rowId` using a request-scoped provider?

If anyone could put me on the correct path, I'd be greatful! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems here. One is that you have this `DAOProviderFactory` and `DAOProviderFactoryImpl`, which require a `rowId` to be able to create a `DAOProviderImpl`, but you never make use of them. I'm also not sure how Guice is even running this at all, since there's no `@Inject` on `DAO`'s constructor and since you don't have any actual custom `DAO` provider bound here.

Anyway, I think you can do something simpler here. Just make a `DAOFactory` like this:

```
@RequestScoped
public class DAOFactory {
  private final Map<Integer, DAO> daos = new HashMap<Integer, DAO>();

  public DAO getDao(int rowId) {
    DAO dao = daos.get(rowId);
    if (dao == null) {
      dao = new DAO(rowId);
      daos.put(rowId, dao);
    }
    return dao;
  }
}
```

It could implement some interface of course if you want. If for some reason you don't know the `rowId` in every place you're retrieving the `DAO`, you could instead do something where you first have to initialize the factory by setting its `rowId` and then have it just return the `DAO` that was created elsewhere.

Anyway, you'd then inject a `Provider<DAOFactory>` (request scoped) in your `WebPage` or wherever.

All that said, I can't help but think there might be some better overall design for you, but not knowing more I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: Indeed, I don't know the `rowId` in every place, so I am trying to initialize the factory by setting its `rowId`, but cannot find a good way of doing that. Since that factory would also require `rowId` to be initialized there is not easy way to create a `Provider<DAOFactory>`. Instead of `Provider<DAOFactory>` I could define a `DAOFactoryFactory` with `DAOFactory create(int rowId)` method. That works, but not only it's quite an overkill, it does not reuse `Provider<T>` which *seems* suitable for this kind of task. Or I am doing this completely wrong?:((

Comment: @rodion: Well, one alternative would be to give your `DAO` class a `setRowId()` method and have that initialize the row. Then you could just inject `Provider<DAO>` wherever. You would of course need to make sure that `setRowId()` is always called before any of the `get` methods. `Provider` is for dynamically retrieving instances of types that are bound in the `Injector`. When something requires information (such as the row ID here) that is only available as the application is used, a factory of some sort is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Personally, I don't like setters, so I'd rather avoid that method. By the way, I tried making `DAOFactory` implement `Provider<DAO>`, and then creating a factory that would create `Provider<DAO>` objects based on a `rowId` (i.e. `Provider<DAO> create(int rowId)`), but Guice refused to bind it. However, when I replaced `Provider<DAO>` with an identical `MyProvider<DAO>` it worked. There appears to be some contraint on `Provider` inteface in Guice. Do you know if there is a way to get around this constraint?

Comment: @rodion: Where and how would you call `Provider<DAO> create(int rowId)`? You aren't going to be able to bind that provider dynamically for each request. With a custom scope, you could seed the scope with a `DAO` (or a row ID). As far as the `Provider` thing, I'm guessing you're trying to `bind(...).to(provider)` when you need to use `bind(...).toProvider(provider)`.

Comment: For instance: the first time the user logs in, the log-in request calls `Provider<UserPageDAO> create(int userId)` method and instantiates `WebPage` with it (actually `WebPage` is not injected by Guice directly, the `@Inject` annotation is a mistake). `WebPage` object stays in the session, while the `get()` requests on the `Provider<UserPageDAO>` will return a per-request-instance. As for the second question, I am using assisted injection of `rowId`, so I am using `FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(new TypeLiteral<Provider<DAO>>(){}, DAOFactory.class).build(ProviderDAOFactory.class)`.